# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

first post here. I tried searching around the forum but none of the answers seems to work in my case.
I'm pretty new to React, and have an issue with my onChange handler.

**In my parent component I have the following:**

```
    // User registration - Onchange handler

    const handleChange = (value, event) => {
      // console.log(event.target.value);
      setFormValue({
        ...formValue,
        [event.target.name]: value,
      });
    };
```

And basically the parent component renders a multi step registration form, which renders the different components based on a state, here is the conditional for the username:

```
 {step === 1 ? <Username handleChange={handleChange} formValue={formValue} /> : null}
```

**In the child I have the following input component:**

```
export const Username = ({formValue, handleChange}) => {
  const username = formValue; 
  
    return (
      <View>
      <Input 
      placeholder="Username..."
      onChangeText={handleChange}
      value={formValue.username}
      name={username} />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

**And the input component:**

```
const Input = (props, name) => {

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.inputSection, inputAnimated]}>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={props.placeholder} placeholderTextColor={theme.colors.lightP} fontSize={16} {...props}/>
    </Animated.View>
  )
}
```

I'm not sure why I get the error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target)

Would appreciate any help.
Console.log of event.target returns undefined.

Comment: Refer to [the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in the documentation you [can read for the onChange event](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchange)

You are using [onChangeText](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext)

So onChangeText has just text value, but if you want to have the native event you have to use onChange.

Then access it in you method

```
    const handleChange = ({ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }) => {
      // console.log(event.target.value);
      setFormValue({
        ...formValue,
        [target]: text,
      });
    };
```

> EDITED

Since asked again how to access the name of text input.
Here this link shows [how to handle text input](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-text-input#:%7E:text=and%20iOS%20guides-,Handling%20Text%20Input,-TextInput%20is%20a)

---

Also you can do it like this:
For example in your method you are giving a name from parameters, you can pass that name to the handler parameter :

```
export const Username = ({formValue, handleChange}) => {
  const username = formValue; 
  
    return (
      <View>
      <Input 
      placeholder="Username..."
      onChangeText={(value)=>handleChange(value,username)} {/* here username is the name you are passing to the value */}
      value={formValue.username}
      name={username} />
      </View>
    )
  }

// then in your handle method
   const handleChange = (value,name) => {
      setFormValue({
        ...formValue,
        name: value,
      });
    };
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply, how will I pass it to the Input component? To link it to my state? I can't seem to make it work, I need to write to formValue.username in my input component.

Comment: @SirAskALot Hello, please check the edited code, if this answers your question please mark it as the correct answer, also please ask if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because onChangeText passes the input's value automatically to the function that's assigned to it, not passing the event itself

If you want to use the event => use onChange instead of onChangeText